# Including Tess4J to a Java project as library in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, ocr, tesseract

I have an so far empty and clean Eclipse Java project.
What do I have to do to use `Tess4J` as library for my web service that I want to develop?
*Is it even possible to use it as library for an Android project? (would be shortcutting a lot)* There is an issue regarding `.tif` with android that I came across.

Tess4J is a wrapper for native code, because tesseract-ocr is written in C/C++. That I've got so far. But how to include this wrapper into my project?

I've googled a lot until I have decided to drop `tesseract.Net`, beacuse this project is badly maintained/documented and would force me to C# (which would be okay), but I didn't manage to get it to work, so I had to default to C/C++ (which is not okay) ;)

I'm kind of lost right now, so any help is welcome.
regards.

**Edit: followed the steps mentioned [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tess4j/forums/forum/1202294/topic/4506433) (answer from nguyenq)**

1: new Eclipse workspace

2: created a new dir called `lib`

3: copied `\Tess4J\dist\tess4j.jar`, `\Tess4J\lib\jna.jar` and `\Tess4J\lib\jai_imageio.jar` into `lib` (2)

4: created a new Java project in Eclipse

5: in project properties (4) I added the .jars from (3) to Java build path as external jars under libraries

6: I copied the dir `\tessdata` and `libtesseract302.dll` into the project root dir `\workspace\project\`

7: I created a new class `Main` and instantiated a `Tesseract1 tesseract = new Tesseract1();` for testing

8: I run the application but an Exception was thrown: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libtesseract302' Module not found`

**Edit2:**

7.1: I created a new class `Main` and instantiated a `Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract.getInstance();` for testing (source: [here](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/codesample.html))

8.1: looked okay so far, but no logic implemented, just tried to build it.

**Edit3:**

9: nope, doesn't work. Still UnsatisfiedLinkError. Could it may be an issue regarding 32-bit vs. 64-bit?
I'am working on Win7 64bit.

Comment: Oh, almost forgot: It has to be the tesseract 3.x engine, because of the multi column support.

Comment: This [Apache licensed app](http://code.google.com/p/mezzofanti/) may be a good point to start - its tesseract 2.03, so there's probably a lot of work to adapt it to 3.x.

Comment: More interesting than which OS you're working on is: which JVM are you executing your application on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow the steps described in the following link to get Tess4J to run in Eclipse:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tess4j/forums/forum/1202294/topic/4506433

I'm not sure the library would run on Android because it seems JNA support on the platform is not there yet.

If you want a .NET wrapper for Tesseract 3.01, take a look at https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract-ocr-dotnet.

Comment: Thanks so far! Could you be so kind and look over my steps, I wrote as edit in my question? Seems there is a minor glitch I can't find.

Comment: The project structure and file placement look correct. You missed 1 file, liblept168.dll, which is the Leptonica library that libtesseract302.dll needs to manipulate images. Be sure to add the sample image eurotext.tif to workspace\project\ also.

Comment: switching to an 32 bit JRE seems to do the trick. Now it gets confused with "\" and "/" while loading the traineedata, but if I have solved this, I think I'll be able to use Tess4J.

Comment: Congrat! I was about to ask about the JDK bit-ness since you had mentioned it, but you've figured it out already. Both Tesseract and Leptonica DLLs are 32-bit binary.

Answer (score 0):

This problem causes because the .dll libraries does not support for 64bit version of Eclipse and JDK(with JRE). You have to install 32bit version of JDK and the Eclipse and repeat this process again. Working fine for me.

Comment: Thanks, that was already discussed. And the bitness of IDE doesn't matter in this case.