# library compilation error for TESS4J ( tesseract ) with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ocr, jna, tesseract

I get this error when i try to compile the example code that is given by tess4j developpers 
i did all they asked i followed the steps in this thread [trying to use tess4j for the first time with eclipse(any step by step for truly beginner)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815978/including-tess4j-to-a-java-project-as-library-in-eclipse)

and a lot other methods but nevertheless i didn't succeed 
i get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.sun.jna.Structure.getFieldOrder()Ljava/util/List;
at com.sun.jna.Structure.fieldOrder(Structure.java:831)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.getFields(Structure.java:857)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.deriveLayout(Structure.java:983)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.calculateSize(Structure.java:908)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.calculateSize(Structure.java:896)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.allocateMemory(Structure.java:357)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:191)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:180)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:167)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:159)
at net.sf.ghost4j.GhostscriptLibrary$display_callback.<init>(GhostscriptLibrary.java:72)
at net.sf.ghost4j.Ghostscript.buildNativeDisplayCallback(Ghostscript.java:315)
at net.sf.ghost4j.Ghostscript.initialize(Ghostscript.java:281)
at net.sf.ghost4j.example.DisplayCallbackExample.main(DisplayCallbackExample.java:48)
```

please i really need your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either use an older version of JNA (<3.5) or revise the structure definitions to include the (now required) [`getFieldOrder()`](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Structure.html#getFieldOrder%28%29) method.

Comment: it was because of the DLLs they were compiled in WIN 32bit so i had to use windows and 32bit jre or recompile the source code of the dlls. eventually i used a 32bit PC (windows).thanks for the answer