# How to use tesseract OCR in android and in eclipse and in java

Tags: android, android-ndk, tesseract, tess4j

I am making an app that wants to use tesseract OCR library. But tesseract is written in C++. So I wnt for tess4J. I read tutorials how to use it in eclipse and in android project. I followed this question ([Including Tess4J to a Java project as library in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815978/including-tess4j-to-a-java-project-as-library-in-eclipse)) but the steps written are not helping me. Please guid me in how to use tesseract library in android app and in eclipse with java as code base.

Answer (score 1):

For Eclipse, try the [Development with Tess4J in NetBeans, Eclipse, and command-line](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial/) tutorial.